# jQuery: remove all but first 4 characters from data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I'm trying to remove all but the first 4 characters from a data attribute of each div, the markup below as follows:
HTML

```
<div class="grid-block" data-category="17.40—18.20">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="18.40—19.40">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="19.20—20.20">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="20.40—21.30">text</div>
```

and the desired result would be this:

```
<div class="grid-block" data-category="1740">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="1840">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="1920">text</div>
<div class="grid-block" data-category="2040">text</div>
```

ideally removing the dot from each too, but that's not essential. Not sure if this is possible, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over all the elements with `[data-category]` attributes, and remove the `.` character from the attribute and then use `.substring(0, 4)` to retrieve the first 4 characters:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4anpn8g/)

```
$('[data-category]').each(function () {
    var category = $(this).data('category').replace('.', '').substring(0, 4);
    $(this).attr('data-category', category);
});
```

---

You don't need jQuery to do this, though:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/q88t701z/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-category]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
    var category = el.dataset.category.replace('.', '').substring(0, 4);
    el.setAttribute('data-category', category);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try `replace` and `subString` to get your result

something like:

```
var x = document.getElementByClassName("grid-block")[0];
var inner = x.innerHTML;
inner = inner.replace('-','').replace('.','').subString(0,4); // subString(start,length)
x.innerHTML = inner;
```